# Cant unit test application with manual bootstrap in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my code needs to do manual bootstrap cause requires loading files before laoding application.

```
var bootstrapModule = angular.module('bootstrapModule', []);

  // the bootstrapper service loads the config and bootstraps the specified app
  bootstrapModule.factory('bootstrapper', function ($http, $log, $q, $timeout) {
    return {
        bootstrap: function (appName) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('config/urls/development.json')
                .success(function (data) {
                  .....
                    deferred.resolve();
                })
                .error(function (data) {
                   ...
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});

// create a div which is used as the root of the bootstrap app
var appContainer = document.createElement('div');

// in run() function you can now use the bootstrapper service and shutdown the bootstrapping app after initialization of your actual app
bootstrapModule.run(function (bootstrapper) {

    bootstrapper.bootstrap('angular3App').then(function () {
        // removing the container will destroy the bootstrap app
        if (appContainer) appContainer.remove();
    });

});

// make sure the DOM is fully loaded before bootstrapping
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(appContainer, ['bootstrapModule']);
});
```

I want my unit tests to replicate this behaviour so it can have the info in the loaded file.

I am trying to bootstrap my app in beforeEach but it is not working.

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
        var bootstrapModule = module('bootstrapModule')
// create a div which is used as the root of the bootstrap app
        var appContainer = document.createElement('div');

// in run() function you can now use the bootstrapper service and shutdown the bootstrapping app after initialization of your actual app
        bootstrapModule.run(function (bootstrapper) {

            bootstrapper.bootstrap('angular3App').then(function () {
                // removing the container will destroy the bootstrap app
                appContainer.remove();
            });

        });

// make sure the DOM is fully loaded before bootstrapping
        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            angular.bootstrap(appContainer, ['bootstrapModule']);
        });

    });
```

It is not bootstrapping accordingly. The information in my scope that is dependent from load of the bootstrapped loaded file is not available.

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: I'm looking to do something similar. Did you find a good solution?

Comment: hi, I know it was over a two years ago but I have a similar issue, did you guys solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I just dealt with this issue and it seems that at least one other person has recently had a similar issue.  I was banging my head against the wall to get my unit tests to run with a setup my like @saulovenancio. The factory was a way I found to import the `config.json` file needed for the project and it worked - it just didn't play nice with our tests.

As far as I could tell, the tests were trying to run before the promise in the `bootstrapMOodule.factory` was resolved. Luckily, while loading the config JSON was a requirement - loading it via service was not a project requirement - so I scrapped the service that was fetching the JSON.

I pretty much followed the approach outlined here: 
[How to configure your AngularJS application using environment variables](http://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-configure-your-angularjs-application-using-environment-variables/)

In the `index.html` document I added a script tag for an `env.js` file before the file that loads my angular app.

```
<html>

...
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Gets the config.json -->
<script src="env.js"></script>
<!-- The App -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

The `env.js` file contains the code that loads the `config.json` onto the window.  Mine looks something like this:

```
(function (window) {

    window.__env = window.__env || {};

    $.get( 'config.json', function( data ){
       window.__env = data;
    })
    .error( function handleErrorResponse( xhr, status, error ){
        console.error( "An AJAX error occured: " + status + "\nError: " + error ) ;
    });

}(this));
```

From here I just loaded the window.__env into my `main.js` file and used it for my constants.

```
var env = {};

if(window){
    Object.assign(env, window.__env);
}

...

angular.module('app').constant('AppSettings', env);
```

Once I made those changes everything worked like a charm ... big thanks to  [Jurgen Van de Moere](http://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-configure-your-angularjs-application-using-environment-variables/).  Hopefully, this will be helpful to someone.